# Remove subdomain URLS from Google search console without removing WWW

Tags: google-search-console, subdomain, multi-subdomains

There are two subdomains for my website. The subdomain for the production site is `www.example.com`. The subdomain for the test site is `test.example.com`.

`test.example.com` is showing up in Google search results and needs to be removed. I have added a `robot.txt` file and set up basic authentication for test.example.com to keep Google from crawling the site in the future.

Is it possible to remove URLS that contain test.example.com without removing [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)? Google search console states `"All URL variations (www/non-www and http/https) will be affected"`. Does this mean if I remove https://test.example.com, https://test.example.com/page1.html, https://test.example.com/page2.html then https://www.example.com, https://www.example.com/page1.html, https://www.example.com/page2.html will also be removed?

**UPDATE:** I decided not to add basic authentication. I'm redirecting any test pages in the Google search to the production site. `robot.txt` contains the following:

```
User-agent: * Disallow: /
```

It is my understanding that this can take weeks to remove the sight from Google search. Is there a way to make this happen sooner without affecting SEO on the production site?

Comment: Is the robots.txt behind the basic authentication?  If so, it isn't doing anything (which is probably a good thing.)  If not, it is preventing Googlebot from crawling the URLs on the test subdomain and seeing that they require authentication now.

Comment: I decided not top add basic authentication. I'm redirecting any test pages in the google search to the production site.

Robot.txt contains the following:

I decided not top add basic authentication. I'm redirecting any test pages in the google search to the production site.


Robot.txt contains the following:


User-agent: *
Disallow: /



It is my understanding that this can take weeks to remove the sight from google search. Is there a way to make this happen sooner without effecting SEO on the production site?

Comment: If you are redirecting, users who click from search will get to the right place, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.  Again, your robots.txt file is preventing Googlebot from seeing your redirects, so it should probably be removed.

Comment: For your comment question "Is there a way to make this happen sooner". I'm new to using GSC, but have you tried the "Removals" feature (in the "Indexing" group)? This is what I did recently for subdomains. I'm still wondering how the subdomains got indexed in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions

- Use `<meta name='robots' content='noindex'>` on all pages of your test site
- Remove any links from your production site to the test site
- Create a login page, for example `test.example.com/login` and dont have a link to it anywhere
- On your login page, add a token (or more) in the `SESSION` variable
- On all other pages, if the token is not there, redirect to the main site
- Remove your pages at [Remove Outdated Content](https://search.google.com/search-console/remove-outdated-content)